# AWS - getting API-Gateway apiID from lambda name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I have a lambda which should be invoked from a public URL (through API-Gateway - no authorization needed)

I know I can fetch public URL by calling `awsSdk.apiGateway.getApi(apiId)`

So I need to get `apiId` from somewhere. I've heard that it's possible to fetch `api-id` by `lambda-name`, but I can't find it in docs.

Is it really possible? the alternative is to keep `api-id` in my app's config (instead of `lambda-name`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by using a lambda name, you **can't get** `apiId`. Maybe what you heard is that in the lambda you can get the `apiId` and then return it to the caller. This would make sense as `apiId` is part of the [event object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) that API gateway passes to the lambda function with each request.

To get the `apiId` from lambda name only, you would have to develop your own **custom solution** for that. This would still be problematic, because a single lambda can be associated with multiple APIs, thus you would probably have to account for that as well.

The simplest way to develop such a solution would be to **store associations** between APIs and its lambda functions in, e.g. DynamoDB table, and query the table when needed to get the `apiId` based on lambda name only.

Answer (score 1):

if your lambda is used with proxy integration, you can retrieve the ID in the input data as explain on this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html)

```
"requestContext": {
  ...
  "apiId": "gy415nuibc"
},
```